# How to pad output (print, .format, etc)

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement something like the following in a program.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
for i in range(20, -1, -1):
    print(str(i) + "|")
```

The output looks like this:

```
20|
19|
...etc
5|
4|
...etc
```

The `|` is always printed right after the number, however I want the `|` to be aligned when printed, so that my output looks like this:

```
20|
19|
...etc
5 | <--Notice a space after single digit
4 |
...etc
```

I tried various ways using `print` and `.format`, but I can't solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> for i in range(20, -1, -1):
    print('{:<2}|'.format(i))


20|
19|
18|
17|
16|
15|
14|
13|
12|
11|
10|
9 |
8 |
7 |
6 |
5 |
4 |
3 |
2 |
1 |
0 |
```

`<` means left aligned. `2` can be changed to however many you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method out:

```
for i in range(20, -1, -1):
    print('{:>5}'.format(str(i)+'|'))
```

Further reference @https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score -1):

Also Work :

```
for i in range(20, -1, -1):
    print(str(i).rjust(width) + "|")
```

Output:

```
20|
19|
18|
17|
16|
15|
14|
13|
12|
11|
10|
9 |
8 |
7 |
6 |
5 |
4 |
3 |
2 |
1 |
0 |
```

Comment: This will put the padding after the '|' character. If you want to use this method you'd need `print((str(i).rjust(width) + "|"))`

Comment: i am not lying @jamlak, open Terminal and check