# How to dynamically pad output?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following code:

```
 lim = #whatever number
 for i in range(lim, -1, -1):
    print(str(i) + "|")
```

If, for example, `lim` is 20, the output is:

```
20|
19|
...etc
5|
4|
...etc
```

The `|` is always printed right after the number, however I want the `|` to be aligned when printed, so that my output looks like this:

```
20|
19|
...etc
5 | <--Notice a space after single digit
4 |
...etc
```

Now, this is easy if one knows how many digits `lim` has, for example, if I knew it had 2 digits I could use the following:

```
print('{:<2}|'.format(i))
```

However, how would I keep the `|` symbols aligned if I did not know the digits of `lim` beforehand. For example, suppose the user is allowed to enter any value for `lim`, how do I make sure that everything is aligned properly?

Comment: you could calculate the number of digits after taking the input, i dont see the problem

Comment: By your previuos question's answer you could have do ii easliy.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738812/how-to-pad-output-print-format-etc

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay Maybe you could have, otherwise I wouldn't have asked. Plus this is my first time handling output with Python, I'm simply not used to it.

Comment: @migdal the problem was, after calculating the number of digits, I didn't know how to implement that using print or format, as jamylak did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `log`

```
from math import log
pad = int(log(lim, 10)) # lim can't be 0

for i in range(lim, -1, -1):
    print('{num:<{pad}}|'.format(pad=pad, num=i))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `len` of lim to build the format before printing:

```
>>> lim=123
>>> f = '{:<'+str(len(str(lim)))+'}|'
>>> f.format(2)
'2  |'
>>> lim=1234
>>> f = '{:<'+str(len(str(lim)))+'}|'
>>> f.format(2)
'2   |'
```

Comment: This is the other way to go, the length of the string, but i don't know which is better, maybe depends on your preference

Comment: Well, I clearly prefer your solution… Mine is more a naive approach I would say.

Comment: I don't think so, thinking about it now this seems safer (however i'd still use my formatting)

Comment: @fredtantini your answer was helpful as well, decided to go with whoever answered fastest :P